# Apply t-test and Wilcoxon-test on several variables in a table

Tags: r, testing, statistics

I want to apply a Mean t-Test and a Median Wilcoxon-test for the two subgroups of all variables but the grouping variable and the Obs.Number in my Data-table. I have two Groups: Group 0 and Group 1. My data looks like this:

```
Obs.Number     Var1         Var2      Var3     Var4      Var5       Var6   GroupingVar
     1        32153.00    48516.00   0.3687    0.0160   12.4288   28646.0       0     
     2        22465.00    34494.00   0.1804    0.0213   10.5003   20988.0       1
     3         1393.10     4257.40  10.1413    0.0359   53.2323     127.3       1      
     4            0.99      164.07   0.4906    0.0817 -989.5800       0.0       1
     5         4745.60     5712.80   0.4914    0.1766   62.5905    2488.7       1
     6        10222.80     9898.20   0.8993    0.0115   15.6440    7665.1       0
        ...
```

Now I want to apply the two tests on all variables to get an output that looks like this:

```
              Test-Statistic    Test-Statistic               p-value        p-value
              for Mean T-test   for Wilcoxon Median-test     of Mean-test   of Median-test

Variable 1     ?                  ?                            ?             ?
Variable 2     ?                  ?                            ?             ?
...
```

I used t.test() and wilcox.test() with sapply(), however I had no success. Any ideas how to get the result?

Comment: Can you show us what code you tried with `sapply`?

Comment: Can you do a ```dput()``` of your data if it is a big dataframe please do ```head(dput(youredata))```

Comment: My data-file is huge. I don't think that it is a good idea to present the head(dput())-output here? The example in the first box of my question is a snippet of my data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the job done (albeit very inelegantly):

```
## using am as the grouping variable
data.frame(stats_t = apply(subset(mtcars, select=-am), 2, function(y) t.test(y ~ mtcars$am)$statistic),
           p_t     = apply(subset(mtcars, select=-am), 2, function(y) t.test(y ~ mtcars$am)$p.value),
           stats_w = apply(subset(mtcars, select=-am), 2, function(y) wilcox.test(y ~ mtcars$am, exact = FALSE)$statistic),
           p_w     = apply(subset(mtcars, select=-am), 2, function(y) wilcox.test(y ~ mtcars$am, exact = FALSE)$p.value)
)

        stats_t          p_t stats_w          p_w
mpg  -3.7671231 1.373638e-03    42.0 1.871391e-03
cyl   3.3541138 2.464713e-03   194.0 3.899814e-03
disp  4.1977266 2.300413e-04   214.0 5.493451e-04
hp    1.2661888 2.209796e-01   176.0 4.570132e-02
drat -5.6460883 5.266742e-06    24.0 1.426919e-04
...
```